# Aitkens Extrapolation

Tags: numerical-methods, fixed-point-theorems

The Aitken's extrapolation can be written as $$X^n = X_{n-2} + \dfrac{(X_{n-1}- X_{n-2})^2}{(X_{n-1}- X_{n-2})-(X_n- X_{n-1})}$$

Verify it?

And $X^n$ can be viewed as being defined recursively by 
$$
Z_{n+1}= Z_n + \frac{\bigl(g(Z_n)- Z_n\bigr)^2}{\bigl(g(Z_n)- Z_n\bigr)-\bigl(g(g(Z_n))- g(Z_n)\bigr)}
$$ 
Verify it for $|g'(X_n)|≠0$ or $1$, and show that $Z_n$ converges quadratically to $r$ even if $|g'(X_n)|> 1$ and the original iteration $X_{n+1}= g(X_n)$ diverges.

I am supposed to use the hint: 
$g(x) = (x-r)h(r) + r$, where $h(r)= g'(r)≠0$.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: OMG! That was lots of editing from me. You have to learn LaTeX. It's easy.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know LaTeX nor have the time to learn it now. Thanks for editing :)
Note: (g(Zn)−Zn)^2 is missing a parenthesis.

Comment: See also [Prove that Aitken's method improves the speed of convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2490622/115115), [Use Steffensen&#39;s method to find $p_{0}^{(1)}$.}](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2474282/115115)

Answer (score 1):

**Aitken's Extrapolation** assumed $ΔX$ is geometric sequence.
Based on the trend of the numbers, we can extrapolate where it ends up.

$\large r = {ΔX_{i} \over ΔX_{i-1}} = {X_{i+1}\;-\;X_{i} \over X_{i}\;-\;X_{i-1}} = constant$

$\large 1-r = {ΔX_{i-1}\;-\;ΔX_{i} \over ΔX_{i-1}}$

$\begin{align}X_{\infty} 
&= X_i + ΔX_i + ΔX_{i+1} +\; ΔX_{i+2}\;+\;... \cr 
&= X_i + ΔX_i\;(1 + r + r^2 +\;...) \cr
&= X_i + {ΔX_i \over 1-r} \cr
&= (X_{i+1} - ΔX_i) - {ΔX_i\;ΔX_{i-1} \over ΔX_{i}-ΔX_{i-1}} \cr
&= X_{i+1} - {ΔX_i(ΔX_{i}-ΔX_{i-1})+ΔX_i\;ΔX_{i-1} \over ΔX_{i}-ΔX_{i-1}} \cr
&= X_{i+1} - {(ΔX_i)^2 \over ΔX_{i}-ΔX_{i-1}} \cr
\end{align}$

We don't know $X_{i+1}$, but with same trend, we can shift the index.
$$X_{\infty} = X_{i} - {(ΔX_{i-1})^2 \over ΔX_{i-1}-ΔX_{i-2}}$$

This verified wikipedia's [Aitken Delta-Square Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aitken%27s_delta-squared_process)

Comment: You could just simply have shifted the index in the $1-r$ formula, $1-r=\frac{ΔX_i−ΔX_{i+1}}{ΔX_i}$ to get the Aitken delta-squared process in the usual notation $X_∞\approx X_i-\frac{(ΔX_i)^2}{ΔX_{i+1}-ΔX_i}$.

Comment: Yes.  I finished the prove and noticed I should shift in the beginning.  Too lazy is do all the editing.  Also, wikipedia formula use x(n), x(n+1), x(n+2) as the 3 points.