# Let $g(x)= \cos(x-1)$ and $p_{0}^{(0)}=2$. Use Steffensen's method to find $p_{0}^{(1)}$.

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods

Let $g(x)= \cos(x-1)$ and $p_{0}^{(0)}=2$. Use Steffensen's method to find $p_{0}^{(1)}$.

---

$$
  \begin{array}{r|lll}
     n & P_{0,n} & P_{1,n} &P_{2,n}& P_{3,n} \\ \hline
     0 & 2.0& .5403023059&.8961866647& .9946162335 \\
     1 & .826427396  &  &      & 
  \end{array}
$$

---

\begin{align}
p_{1,0} &= g(p_{0}^{(0)}) =\cos(2-1) &&= .5403023059 \\ 
p_{2,0} &=g(p_{1}^{(0)})=\cos(.5403023059-1)&&= .8961866647\\ 
p_{3,0} &=g(p_{2}^{(0)})= \cos(8961866647-1)&&=.9946162335
\end{align}

---

How does one find $p_{0}^{(1)}$?This is what I have attempted. 
Aitkens $△^2$ method.

\begin{align}
△^kp_{n}&=△(△^{k-1}p_n)\\ 
p&= p_{n}-\frac{(p_{n+1}-p_n)^2}{p_{n+2}-2p_{n+1}+p_n} \\
p_0^{(1)}&=p_1-\frac{(p_2-p_1)^2}{(p_3-2p_2+p_1)} \\ 
p_0^{(1)}&= .5403023059-(\frac{(.8961866647-.5403023059)^2}{.9946162335-2*.8961866647+.5403023059}) = 1.032247618
\end{align}

I am having trouble deriving the answer, does anyone know the correct way to solve this problem or any tips hints on where I made a mistake?

Comment: You know you can use `\cos` instead of `\text{cos}`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aitken's method for accelerating the fixed-point iteration $x_+=g(x)$ is Steffensen's root-finding method for $f(x)=g(x)-x$. So it seems that what you are doing is right. There appears to be some fluidity in the naming of these less-known methods. By the indexing of the variables in the task one would assume that Aitken's method is to be used.

Your specific problem is that while the method calls for using the index range $[0,1,2]$, you apply the method using the index range $[1,2,3]$. While the resulting method will still converge accelerated, it will not follow the path of the correct method.

```
In [1]: from math import cos
In [2]: def g(x) : return cos(x-1)
In [3]: def aitken(g,p0) : p1=g(p0); p2=g(p1); return p0 - (p1-p0)**2/(p2-2*p1+p0);
In [4]: aitken(g,2)
Out[4]: 0.8264273956775894
```

Following the correct iteration to the end gives

```
In [5]: p=2;
In [6]: for k in range(8): print k,p; p=aitken(g,p)
0 2
1 0.826427395678
2 1.00143549146
3 0.999999999261
4 1.0
------------------------------------------------
ZeroDivisionError
```

Using the wrong iteration formula gives

```
In [7]: def wrong(g,p0) : p1=g(p0); p2=g(p1); p3=g(p2); return p1 - (p2-p1)**2/(p3-2*p2+p1);
In [8]: p=2;
In [9]: for k in range(8): print k,p; p=wrong(g,p)
0 2
1 1.03224761726
2 1.00000000004
---------------------------------------------
ZeroDivisionError
```

Comment: Yes you are correct I made a mistake in the starting iterations it should be more like $$p_0^{1}=p_0^{0}-\frac{(p_1^{0}-p_0^{0})^2}{p_2^{0}-2p_1^{0}+P_0^{0}}$$