# Simplified Explanation of Shanks Transformation

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods

I am currently working on a project for a competition and during research came across shanks transformation. After reading a bit from here and there I am still a bit confused.....Can someone pls explain the basics of it (keep in mind that I am a high school sophomore, so pls keep the explanation a bit simple). Also, I just wanted to ask one particular doubt that I read in an article about it

''The idea behind Shanks transformation is quite simple. If we observe exponentially converging series, we can take groups of 3 neighbouring points. For each 3 points, we can fit exponent a + b exp(c*n). If n goes to infinity, then this exponent approximates a.''

Link for article - https://medium.com/@stiv.yakovenko/speed-up-your-calculations-with-the-magic-of-shanks-transformation-dd7a00dab4a6

In this explanation, if n tends to infinity then shouldn't the exponent tend to infinity as well??

Comment: You get $a_n$, $b_n$, $c_n$ and the $c_n$ may converge to some $\alpha$ that is valid for the whole series. Note that "exponentially converging" implies that the $c_n$ and $\alpha$ are negative, so that the $a_n$, if everything converges, converge to the limit of the sequence. // Here it would make sense to have a link to or a picture of the quote available.

Comment: I have now attached the link for the quote

Comment: This is similar to Aitkens delta-squared process. Only that there you leave the original sequence and use $S(A_n)$ to restart the original iteration. This gives in many occasions Newton-like performance. If one considers this as some kind of Newton method, then it is also called Steffensen's method. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2490622/prove-that-aitkens-method, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2474282/let-gx-cosx-1-and-p-00-2-use-steffensens-method

Answer (score 1):

What the quote means is if one fits the exponential function $a+be^{cn}$ to the sequence $A_n$, then in the given situation $c<0$ so that for $n\to\infty$ the exponential expression converges to $a$. Thus $a$ is the current estimate for the limit of the sequence.

The computation of the coefficients is
$$
\left.\begin{aligned}
A_{n-1}&=a+be^{c(n-1)}\\
A_{n}&=a+be^{cn}\\
A_{n+1}&=a+be^{c(n+1)}\\
\end{aligned}\right\}
\implies
\left.\begin{aligned}
A_{n}-A_{n-1}&=be^{c(n-1)}(e^c-1)\\
A_{n+1}-A_{n}&=be^{cn}(e^c-1)\\
\end{aligned}\right\}
\implies
e^c=\frac{A_{n+1}-A_{n}}{A_{n}-A_{n-1}}
$$
Then inserting backwards
$$
a=A_{n-1}-\frac{A_{n}-A_{n-1}}{e^c-1}
=A_{n-1}-\frac{(A_{n}-A_{n-1})^2}{A_{n+1}-2A_{n}+A_{n-1}}
=\frac{A_{n-1}A_{n+1}-A_{n}^2}{A_{n+1}-2A_{n}+A_{n-1}}
$$
The second form is the one of the Aitken delta-squared process which is related to Steffensen's method. However these last two are not sequence transformations but a different sequence construction. Directly related might be Wynn's epsilon transformation.