# Does Aitken's $\Delta^2$ method asymptotically improve rate of convergence?

Tags: numerical-methods, asymptotics, numerical-calculus, rate-of-convergence

Denoting $y_n = x_n-\frac{(x_{n+1}-x_n)^2}{x_{n+2}-2x_{n+1} +x_n}$
when $x_n\rightarrow_{n\rightarrow\infty} a $ with $p$ convergence order.

I showed that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} |\frac {y_n-a}{x_n-a}| =0$

I wish to show that the method does not improve the rate of convergence asymptotically, i.e $|\frac{y_{n+1}-a}{(y_n-a)^p}| = c_1$ when $|\frac{x_{n+1}-a}{(x_n-a)^p}| = c_2$ .

I first tried to make it work with $p=1$.

I denote $e_n = x_n-x \Rightarrow x_n=e_n +x$.

$x_{n+1} - a-\frac{(x_{n+2}-x_{n+1})^2}{x_{n+3}-2x_{n+2} +x_{n+1}} = $
$e_{n+1}-\frac{(e_{n+2}-e_{n+1})^2}{e_{n+3}-2e_{n+2}+e_{n+1}} = \frac{e_{n+1}e_{n+3} - e_{n+2}^2}{e_{n+3}-2e_{n+2}+e_{n+1}}$

and

$x_n- a -\frac{(x_{n+1}-x_n)^2}{x_{n+2}-2x_{n+1} +x_n} = $
$\frac{e_{n}e_{n+2} - e_{n+1}^2}{e_{n+2}-2e_{n+1}+e_{n}}$

thus

Thus $\frac{y_{n+1}-a}{y_n-a} = \frac{e_{n+1}e_{n+3} - e_{n+2}^2}{e_{n+3}-2e_{n+2}+e_{n+1}} \cdot \frac{e_{n+2}-2e_{n+1}+e_{n}}{e_{n}e_{n+2} - e_{n+1}^2} = \frac{e_{n+2}-2e_{n+1}+e_{n}}{e_{n+3}-2e_{n+2}+e_{n+1}} \cdot \frac{e_{n+1}e_{n+3} - e_{n+2}^2}{e_{n}e_{n+2} - e_{n+1}^2} $

now using $\frac{e_{n+1}}{e_n}\rightarrow c$ then $\frac{e_{n+k}}{e_{n}} \rightarrow c^k$ lets try to divide numerator and denominator of the left expression by $e^n$ and  the right expression by $e_{n+1}^2$ and take the limit:

$\frac{e_{n+2}-2e_{n+1}+e_{n}}{e_{n+3}-2e_{n+2}+e_{n+1}} \cdot \frac{e_{n+1}e_{n+3} - e_{n+2}^2}{e_{n}e_{n+2} - e_{n+1}^2} =_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{c^2-2c+1}{c^3-2c^2+c} \cdot \frac{c^2-c^2}{\frac{1}{c}\cdot c-1} $

the problem is that no matter how I try to manipulate the right expression (for example deviding by $e_{n+2}^2$, it results in $\frac{1}{c} \cdot \frac{0}{0}$ when taking the limits.

Other approaches (especially ones that don't demand so much writing) are more the welcome!

Comment: Aitken's method is able to accelerate linear convergence only is some special cases, for example when $x_n = a + c\lambda^n$ with $|\lambda| < 1$. Without additional assumptions about $x_n$ you will not be able to prove any positive or negative results.

Comment: @PawelKowal Thanks for your comment!, may you please explain why there is no way to get any results without additional assumptions? Or direct me to reference regrading this problem?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2490622/115115, you are applying the delta-squared process wrong. In solving a fixed-point equation $x=f(x)$, to get $x_{n+1}$ you compute $x_n^1=f(x_n)$, $x_n^2=f(x_n^1)$ and apply the Aitken formula to that short sequence, the result is $x_{n+1}$, from which you then compute the next short sequence etc.

Comment: @dan See for example WENIGER, Ernst Joachim. Nonlinear sequence transformations for the acceleration of convergence and the summation of divergent series. Computer Physics Reports, 1989, 10.5-6: 189-371. In general case the Aitken's method transforms a linearly convergent sequence to a linearly convergent sequence. However in some special cases one can obtain superlinear or faster convergence.