Weird behavior in Aitken-accelerated sequence generated by bisection method
I recently stumbled across the Aitken delta-squared process for speeding up convergence of sequences through extrapolation.
It is often said that the signs of each forward difference $\Delta x = x_{n+1}-x_n$ need to agree at some point far in the sequence (for all large $n$) so that the derivation is valid. Otherwise, there is also an extended formula for the case where far $\Delta x_{n+1}$ and $\Delta x_n$ have opposite signs.
I am investigating the behavior of the Aitken-accelerated sequence generated by the bisection method for root-finding (despite $\Delta x_n$ changing signs inconsistently). This is what happened I used the original formulation with
$$a(x_n):=x_n-\frac{(\Delta x_n)^2}{\Delta^2 x_n}$$
Here is a table of the results for the first 50 or so iterations:



Iteration
Bisection Sequence
Sign Change (Bisection)
Aitken Accelerated Sequence




0
1.5
-1
1.3333333333333333


1
1.25
1
1.5


2
1.375
1
1.4166666666666667


3
1.4375
-1
1.4166666666666667


4
1.40625
1
1.4166666666666667


5
1.421875
-1
1.4166666666666667


6
1.4140625
1
1.4166666666666667


7
1.41796875
-1
1.4140625


8
1.41601563
-1
1.4140625


9
1.41503906
-1
1.4140625


10
1.41455078
-1
1.4140625


11
1.41430664
-1
1.4142252604166667


12
1.41418457
1
1.4142252604166667


13
1.41424561
-1
1.41418457


14
1.414215087890625
-1
1.4142049153645833


15
1.4141998291015625
1
1.414215087890625


16
1.4142074584960938
1
1.414215087890625


17
1.4142112731933594
1
1.414215087890625


18
1.4142131805419922
1
1.4142138163248699


19
1.4142141342163086
-1
1.4142131805419922


20
1.4142136573791504
-1
1.414213498433431


21
1.4142134189605713
1
1.4142136573791504


22
1.4142135381698608
1
1.4142135779062908


23
1.4142135977745056
-1
1.4142135381698608


24
1.4142135679721832
-1
1.4142135580380757


25
1.414213553071022
1
1.4142135679721832


26
1.4142135605216026
1
1.4142135630051296


27
1.414213564246893
-1
1.4142135605216026


28
1.4142135623842478
-1
1.414213561763366


34
1.4142135614529252
1
1.4142135623842478


35
1.4142135619185865
1
1.4142135623842478


36
1.4142135621514171
1
1.4142135623842478


37
1.4142135622678325
1
1.4142135623842478


38
1.4142135623260401
1
1.4142135623842478


39
1.414213562355144
1
1.4142135623842478


40
1.4142135623696959
1
1.4142135623745464


41
1.4142135623769718
-1
1.4142135623696959


42
1.4142135623733338
-1
1.4142135623721213


43
1.4142135623715149
1
1.4142135623733338


44
1.4142135623724243
1
1.4142135623733338


45
1.414213562372879
1
1.4142135623730308


46
1.4142135623731065
-1
1.4142135623730308


47
1.4142135623729928
1
1.4142135623731065


48
1.4142135623730496
1
1.4142135623731065


49
1.414213562373078
1
1.4142135623731065


50
1.4142135623730923
1
1.414213562373097


51
1.4142135623730994
-1
1.4142135623730923


52
1.4142135623730958
-1
1.4142135623730947



Originally, I wanted to try to put a stopping condition to check for convergence of the Aitken-accelerated sequence by seeing if the differences at a certain point were very small, similar to the bisection stopping condition, as an indicator of potentially settling down. When I wrote an algorithm like this, I kept getting values quite far away from the root, and was confused. But after analysis, it is pretty evident that it is actually the sequence itself that is stopping in place for a few iterations before jumping somewhere else again.
I found this very strange, and interesting. It is not at all what I would've expected. What gives? Is there a pattern as to when this happens?

The here demonstrated example exhibits a very good behaviour. Where did you get a weird behaviour ?

It gets stuck at some points for several iterations before resuming, that's what I mean

The delta-squared process needs a smooth fixed-point iteration to start with, giving geometric convergence close to the root, which the bisection method is not. Then the method restarts the original iteration every two steps, that is, it computes $x_{n,0}=x_n, x_{n,1},x_{n,2}$ using the original iteration and then computes $x_{n+1}$ as the Aitken value. Doing delta-square piggy-back of the original iteration sequence only provides a modest improvement of the accuracy and no change in the speed of convergence.

So I should apply the Aitken formula to itself, as a recursion? Would it be able to work with the extended formula?

So what's the difference between Aitken's acceleration method and Steffensen's method?

Aitken acceleration applies to fixed-point iterations $x_{n+1}=g(x_n)$. Steffensen's method applies to finding roots of some function/equation $f(x)=0$. They can be connected by setting $f(x)=g(x)-x$, then Steffensen becomes Aitken. I did some deeper review in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2490686/115115
