# Take angle out of tan()

Tags: trigonometry

I have the following formulas:

$$S = 4 \times \tan\left(\frac{180^\circ-a}{2}\right)  - \frac{π}{90^\circ} \times (180^\circ-a)$$

where:

$$S \gt 0$$

$$0^\circ \lt a \lt 180^\circ$$

and I want to solve them by **α** but I don't know how to take **α** out of the **tan()**.
I tried to use some functions with arctan() but with no luck.

Could someone help me out with it?

Comment: I would say that the problem can be solved only by some of the numerical methods.

Comment: I suspect that you mean $180^\circ,90^\circ$ etc. If so, please edit your question. (See [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/19678/1508) for how to get the degree symbol.)

Comment: You are right. α is degrees.

Comment: It's rather unusual to have $\pi$ and degrees mixed up together like that. Are you sure your formula is correct? Where does it come from?

Comment: This formula calculates the area of a triangle that has been cut by a circular sector. That's from where the π comes from.

Comment: A diagram of that circular sector would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your expression, angle in radians

$${S\over4} + {\pi \over 2} =\cot{a\over2} +{a\over2}$$
$$a_{i+1} = 2\cot^{-1}({S \over 4} + {\pi-a_i \over 2})$$

Example, with $S=10, a_0=0$, using [Aitkens Extrapolation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/760708/aitkens-extrapolation/3369554#3369554)

$$Aitken(a_i) = a_{i} - {(a_{i}-a_{i-1})^2 \over a_{i} - 2a_{i-1}+a_{i-2}}$$

$\begin{matrix}
i & a_i & Aitken(a_i) \cr
1 & 0.4817648629 \cr
2 & 0.5108008969 \cr
3 & 0.5126606739 & 0.5127879457\cr
4 & 0.5127884300 \cr
5 & 0.5127884612 & 0.5127884633 \cr
6 & 0.5127884633
\end{matrix}$

---

We can give a better guess for above iterations.
$$S = 4 \cot{a\over2} - 2(\pi-a) = {8 \over a} - 2\pi + {4a \over 3} - {a^3 \over 90}+ O(a^5)$$

Let $b = \large \frac{3}{8}\normalsize (S+2\pi)$
$$b = {3\over a} + {a \over 2} -  {a^3 \over 240} + O(a^5)$$
Drop $O(a^3)$, and solve the quadratic:

$$a ≈ \frac{6}{b + \sqrt{b^2-6}}$$

For $S=10,\quad a ≈ 0.51284 02951,\quad error ≈ 0.010\%$

We can improve the guess by re-using above formula, with a new $b$.
$$b ← b + {1\over240}\left( \frac{6}{b + \sqrt{b^2-6}} \right)^3$$

For $S=10,\quad a ≈ 0.51278 87723,\quad error ≈ 0.000060\%$

Note: the guess goes complex if $S < 8\sqrt{2\over3} - 2\pi ≈ 0.24879$

For small S, I use @Lutz setup, but with $\tan(x)$ [continued fraction representation](http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Tan/10/).

$${S \over 4} ≈ \large{x \over 1- {x^2 \over 3- {x^2\over5}}}-x = 
\large {5x^3 \over 15-6x^2}$$
$$x^3 ≈ S({3\over4}-{3\over10}x^2)$$
Since small S also meant small x, we let $t={3\over4}S$, and keep approximating ...

1st approximation: $x ≈ \sqrt[3]{t(1-\require{cancel} \cancel{{2\over5}x^2)}} ≈ \sqrt[3]{t}$
2nd approximation: $x ≈ \sqrt[3]{t(1-{2\over5}(\sqrt[3]t)^2}$
3rd approximation: $x ≈ \sqrt[3]{t} - {2 \over 15}t \require{cancel} \cancel{-{4\over225}t^{5/3} +\;...}$
$$a = \pi-2x ≈ \pi - \sqrt[3]{6S} + {S \over 5}$$

---

By trial and error, I found a formula that is even better  than solving the cubic exactly!
For small $S$, let $b = \sqrt[3]{6S}$

$$a ≈ \pi - {30b \over 30 + b^2}$$

Comment: For contrast, try with $S=0.3$. Newton slows down noticeably, is Aitken-Steffensen more robust?

Comment: With S=0.3, guess=0, it take 4 Aitken extrapolations to reach 11 digits accuracy.  Total iterations = 1+4*2 = 9 → a =  1.9823781857.  With your better guess, pi - (6S)^(1/3) = 1.9251522545, 3 Aitken steps needed, iterations = 1+3*2 = 7.

Comment: Added a guess section to my answer.  For S=0.3, guess = 1.9851522545

Comment: Added an improved guess formula.  For S=0.3, guess = 1.9823319113

Answer (score 0):

You also have, in the relation of degree and radian units, $\pi=180^∘$, $90^∘=\frac\pi2$ etc. so that the equation reduces to 
$$
\frac{S}4=\tan(x)-x
$$
 where $x=\frac{180^∘−α}2$.

Now apply Newton's method or apply a fixed-point method. For the Newton method consider $f(x)=\arctan(x+\frac S4)-x$. For small $S$, $x$ dominates the sum with $S/4$,see below. Thus $f(x)\sim x^3$. To remove this multiple root, divide by $x^2$ which gives a Newton iteration $N(x)=x-\frac{xf(x)}{xf'(x)-2f(x)}$ which converges very rapidly

A suitable fixed-point equation that works without trying too many alternative formulations is $x=g(x)=\arctan(x+\frac S4)$. It converges reliably, however slowly.

[image: plot of the fixed-point iteration]
<sup>*Iteration $x_{k+1}=g(x_k)$, $x_0=0$, over $S$*</sup>

Finally, convert back $α=180^∘-360^∘\frac{x}\pi$.

---

For small values of $S$ and thus small $x$ this gives approximately 
$$
\frac S4\approx \frac{x^3}3\implies x\approx\sqrt[3]{\frac34S}.
$$ 
For larger $S$ you can use the approximation $\frac{x}{1-4x^2/\pi^2}$ of the tangent function, so that an approximation is obtained as the smaller solution of a quadratic equation.
$$
0=\left(\frac{2x}\pi\right)^2+2\frac{2x}{\pi}\frac{\pi}{S}-1
=\left(\frac{2x}\pi+\frac{\pi}{S}\right)^2-1-\frac{\pi^2}{S^2}
\\
\implies x=\frac\pi2\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{\pi^2}{S^2}}-\frac{\pi}{S}\right)
=\frac{\pi S}{2(\sqrt{S^2+\pi^2}+\pi)}
$$

Comment: Thanks but approximations is not what I am looking for. As I wrote earlier, this formula calculates the area of a triangle (Isosceles) that has been cut by a circular sector on the third side (not the equal ones). α is the angle between the two equal sides. I want to be able to calculate this angle based on the area that I have already (physically) calculated.

Comment: Then apply your favorite numerical solver. In a pinch, iterate $x_{n+1}=\arctan(x_n+\frac S4)$ which will converge. The approximations were not good anyway, they are not compatible, and there is a middle range where both are bad.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from LutzL's answer, we need to find "good" approximation of $x$ such that
$$k=\tan(x)-x \qquad \text{where} \qquad k=\frac S 4$$
For the range $ 0 \leq x \leq \frac \pi 4$, a quite good approximation of the rhs is
$$\tan(x)-x\sim\frac{5 x^3}{15-6 x^2}$$ corresponding to the $[3,2]$ Padé approximant built at $x=0$. As a result, this gives a cubic equation in $x$
$$x^3+\frac{6 k }{5}x^2-3 k=0$$ the only real solution of which being given by
$$\color{blue}{x=\frac{2}{5} k \left(2 \cosh \left(\frac{1}{3} \cosh ^{-1}\left(\frac{375}{16 k^2}-1\right)\right)-1\right)}$$
Below are given some results for comparison
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
k & \text{approximation} & \text{exact} \\
 0.00 & 0.000000 &  0.000000 \\
 0.01 & 0.306774 &  0.306773 \\
 0.02 & 0.383648 &  0.383643 \\
 0.03 & 0.436456 &  0.436446 \\
 0.04 & 0.477750 &  0.477734 \\
 0.05 & 0.512063 &  0.512040 \\
 0.06 & 0.541613 &  0.541582 \\
 0.07 & 0.567670 &  0.567630 \\
 0.08 & 0.591038 &  0.590989 \\
 0.09 & 0.612261 &  0.612203 \\
 0.10 & 0.631728 &  0.631659 \\
 0.11 & 0.649725 &  0.649646 \\
 0.12 & 0.666472 &  0.666382 \\
 0.13 & 0.682141 &  0.682039 \\
 0.14 & 0.696867 &  0.696753 \\
 0.15 & 0.710763 &  0.710637 \\
 0.16 & 0.723922 &  0.723783 \\
 0.17 & 0.736418 &  0.736266 \\
 0.18 & 0.748319 &  0.748154 \\
 0.19 & 0.759678 &  0.759500 \\
 0.20 & 0.770545 &  0.770352 \\
 0.21 & 0.780960 &  0.780753
\end{array}
\right)$$

For the case where $ \frac \pi 4 \leq x \leq \frac \pi 2$, let $t= \frac \pi 2-x$ which makes the equation to be
$$k'=k+\frac \pi 2=t+\cot(t)$$ and using again Padé approximant built at $t=0$
$$t+\cot(t)\sim \frac{1+\frac{7 }{10}t^2}{t+\frac{1}{30}t^3}$$ This again gives a cubic equation in $t$
$$\frac{k' }{30}t^3-\frac{7}{10} t^2+k' t-1=0$$